# Bootstrap: Modal with horizontal form and input addon does not layout properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Rows with inputs seam wider then other rows (example is a button).

http://jsfiddle.net/ujnw8x4p/2/

```html
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal" size="lg" index="0" style="z-index: 1050; display: block;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Bootstrap Modal with horizontal form and input addon</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body ng-scope">
                
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputLinkPp" class="hidden-xs col-sm-3 control-label">Website</label>
                        <div class="input-group col-sm-9 xs-margin">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLinkPp" placeholder="link to your page"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9" style="text-align: right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></i> Create</button>
                        </p>
                    </div>                    
                </form>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

It seams like the modals padding is not respected by the input-group-addon.
But maybe i am not supposed to us input-groups in horizontal forms?

Any ideas on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with this using only the Bootstrap classes. It looks like it accomplishes what you need, the only issue is the vertical alignment on the `<label>` doesn't match up with the `<input>`. Would need some custom css to override that. Here's the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal" size="lg" index="0" style="z-index: 1050; display: block;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
          <h3 class="modal-title">Bootstrap Modal with horizontal form and input addon</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body ng-scope">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 text-right" >
              <label>Website</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLinkPp" placeholder="link to your page"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></i> Create</button>
              </div> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Oh and I accidentally removed the `<form>` tag from it, so that would need to be added back in. Here's a link to the Bootply:

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/UHEG35wn4K)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thx for your input, but i basicly removed the form-horizontal.
I need to check what that means to the whole rest of my form...

Comment: Ah there's more elements eh? `.form-horizontal` is just a class for laying out the form, so it removing it shouldn't effect too much, you may just need to restructure your other `<label>....<input>` pairs to match the one above.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a working solution.
Not sure though whether its the correct way or not.
Added this in my style sheet:

```
.form-horizontal .input-group {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ujnw8x4p/3/